# Create a loop on my pages with new "WP_Query"

Tags: wp-query, loop, pages

I wanted to loop through these four pages. Basically I would like my loop create a "li" by "page_id". I just know this is from my "new WP_Query" which is not good.

How would you be doing? Here is my code:

```
<ul>
<?php $query = new WP_Query('page_id=50' || 'page_id=53' || 'page_id=56' || 'page_id=58'); ?>
<?php while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
    <li>
        <?php the_field('my-content'); ?>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the proper parameter. Try this:

```
$post_ids = array( 50, 53, 56, 58 );
$query = new WP_Query('post__in' => $post_ids );
```

[More info](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-page-parameters)